# Using metaprogramming to write a single spec for multiple workers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have written a sidekiq worker spec. So right now we have four worker with almost the same spec. All spec will be testing for some_method and checking if the job has been equeued or not.

My sample worker code:

```
RSpec.describe HardWorker do
  subject(:worker) { described_class.new }

  describe "perform" do
    let(:some_id) { instance_double("String") }

    it "calls Hard working operation" do
      expect(HardWorkingOperation).to receive(:one_method)
        .with(some_id: some_id)

      worker.perform(some_id)
    end

    it "enqueues a HardWork worker" do
      HardWorker.perform_async(some_id)
      expect(HardWorker.jobs.size).to eq 1
    end
  end
end
```

Second Sample spec:

```
RSpec.describe AnotherWorker do
  subject(:worker) { described_class.new }

  describe "perform" do
    let(:key1){double("Integer")}
    let(:key2){double("String")}
    let(:options) do 
      {
        :key1 => key1, 
        :key2_ref => key2
      }
    end

    it "calls method_data" do
      expect(AnotherOperation).to receive(:another_method)
        .with(options["key1"], options["key2"])

      worker.perform(options)
    end

    it "enqueues a Another worker" do
        AnotherWorker.perform_async(options)
        expect(AnotherWorker.jobs.size).to eq 1
    end
  end
end
```

I want to write a single spec which tests for all workers receiving some method(can be different for respective) and that the job has been enqueued.
How can I best do this? Any suggestion appreciated?

Comment: it would help if you showed two of the "similar" test collections, rather than just one, so that we can know what stuff can be abstracted away. Right now there's no way to answer this.

Comment: both specs are same testing similar scenarios.

Comment: No, these tests are not similar at all. Setup is wildly different, as is one of the tests. In fact, only one test can be parameterized by worker class (the one that checks that a job is enqueued).

Comment: Yes I know that. So is there a way to generalize for different workers.

Comment: By generalizing I meant that first scenario will test whether the worker is receiving some_method which can be different for each worker and the second tests whether the job has been enqueued.

Comment: To extract out the check that it is receiving some method, is possible using the shared examples below too.

Comment: I can see that it is possible using shared-examples. But is there another way to do it better and can be more flexible with code. Suppose we decide on adding another test to the worker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [shared examples](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-0/docs/example-groups/shared-example-group). Assuming all of them have a "operation" class of sorts that will perform a `call`, maybe something like this:

```
shared_examples_for "a sidekiq worker" do |operation_klass|
  subject(:worker) { described_class.new }

  describe "perform" do
    let(:some_id) { instance_double("String") }

    it "calls some operation" do
      expect(operation_klass).to receive(:call).with(some_id: some_id)
      worker.perform(some_id)
    end

    it "enqueues a worker" do
      described_class.perform_async(some_id)
      expect(described_class.jobs.size).to eq 1
    end
  end
end

RSpec.describe HardWorker do
  it_behaves_like "a sidekiq worker", HardWorkingOperation
end
```

If you need to also check that the `call` is done with a different set of arguments each worker, you could pass that in as a hash I guess. But at that point, you should be asking yourself, if that spec really should be extracted out at all :P

```
shared_examples_for "a sidekiq worker" do |operation_klass, ops_args|
  ..
  expect(operation_klass).to receive(:call).with(ops_args)
  ..
end

it_behaves_like "a sidekiq worker", HardWorkingOperation, { some_id: some_id }
```

Comment: This is one solution. Can I achieve something like this metaprogramming. Actually I am trying to learn it, that's why I want to do it only using metaprogramming.

Comment: Yes, nice try. However, you used the first snippet as a base for this. It won't work for the second worker (that test is very different)

Comment: @Ravi: you keep using that word. I don't think you know what it means. Every rspec test file is nothing but a bunch of metaprogramming magic.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev it -has- to be based on the premise that all of the workers would be doing the exact same thing - or rather do a `SomeClass.call` (odd but that seems like what he wanted lol)